# JSONArray needs higher API level, but is used in same class without issue

Tags: java, android, json

This is a reoccurring issues that I keep getting in Android Studio. I will go to use the JSONArray class, and it will tell me that "Call Requires API Level 19(current min is 15)". The weird thing is that I am able to use JSONArray in other spots in the same class.

Some things that I've tried are cleaning and building the project (does nothing), restarting Android Studio (also does nothing for the issue), and rewriting the method that uses JSONArray, or move it (This will sometimes work)

Here is an example where I don't get the issue

```java
private void makeApiCall(String text) {
        APICall.make(context, text, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    employees = new APIHelper().populateEmployeetList(array);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                autoAdapter.setData(employees);
                autoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And here is an example where I get the Error

```java
private void getJobs(String text){
        APICall.getJobsByPartial(context, text, new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {
                try{
                    List<Function> functions = new ArrayList<>();
                    JSONArray jobs = new JSONArray(response);
                    functions = new APIHelper().populateFunctionList(jobs);

                    jobAdapter.setData(functions);
                    jobAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                catch (JSONException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code snippet, `response` is a `String`. The `JSONArray` constructor that takes a `String` has been around since API Level 1.

In your second code snippet, `response` is an `Object`. The `JSONArray` constructor that takes an `Object` has only been around since API Level 19.

In your second code snippet, `APICall.getJobsByPartial()` should be giving your callback something more specific than an `Object`.